# Is goblin dog's allergic reaction automatically removed by cure disease?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, disease

Goblin dog's **allergic reaction** states:
"*Remove disease or any magical healing removes the rash instantly.*"

Does this mean, that you do not need to make a caster level check to remove it, if [Remove disease](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease/) is used?
Also, does this kind of wording in any other monster ability work the same way in regards to effects that automatically remove conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, no caster level check is required.  They use wording like this on effects designed to be minor, to say "you can get rid of it with a variety of minor means." If you could use a Cure Light to get rid of it, then no sense a higher level spell also needing its roll.  Keep in mind Remove Disease also says "The spell also kills some hazards and parasites, including green slime..." outside the scope of the DC vs disease clause so it's even in the spell description that it'll do some things without a roll vs DC.

It's nearly identical to the Irritant ability of the [Pickled Punk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/pickled-punk/). It's similar to Bleeding, which "can be stopped by a DC 15 Heal check or through the application of any spell that cures hit point damage (even if the bleed is ability damage)." It's just an allergic reaction to a dirty goblin dog, no big deal, but you have to spend some kind of resource to dispense with it.